# How can I trim white space from a variable in awk?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

Suppose $2 is my variable.  I have tried going from

```
awk -F\, '{print $2 ":"}'
```

to

```
awk -F\, '{print gsub(/[ \t]+$/, "", $2) ":"}'
```

But it goes from printing something to printing nothing at all.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You're printing the result of the `gsub`, but `gsub` does an in-place modify of `$2` instead of returning a modified copy. Call `gsub`, then print:

```
awk -F\, '{gsub(/[ \t]+$/, "", $2); print $2 ":"}'
```

Answer (score 56):

These functions come in handy to improve readability. They also return the trimmed result:

```
function ltrim(s) { sub(/^[ \t\r\n]+/, "", s); return s }
function rtrim(s) { sub(/[ \t\r\n]+$/, "", s); return s }
function trim(s) { return rtrim(ltrim(s)); }
BEGIN {
# whatever
}
{
# whatever
}
END {
# whatever
}
```

Source: https://gist.github.com/andrewrcollins/1592991

Answer (score 24):

To trim whitespace at the **end** of `$2` use:

```
awk -F\, '{gsub(/[ \t]+$/, "", $2); print $2 ":"}'
```

To trim whitespace at the **beginning** of `$2` use:

```
awk -F\, '{gsub(/^[ \t]+/, "", $2); print $2 ":"}'
```

And for both end and beginning:

```
awk -F\, '{gsub(/^[ \t]+/, "", $2); gsub(/[ \t]+$/, "", $2); print $2 ":"}'
```

Comment: Looks the third line can be abbreviated as `awk -F\, '{gsub(/^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$)/, "", $2); print $2 ":"}'`. Mind that powerful pipe sign! :)

Answer (score 8):

A one liner for gawk:

```
gawk -F\, '{$2 = gensub(/^[ \t]*|[ \t]*$/,"","g",$2)}'
```

Answer (score 3):

ltrim and rtrim in Unix

`awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} {gsub(/^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$/, "", $2)}1' filename.txt`

Answer (score 0):

A more simple option:

You have to define the trim function, the use gsub for a general replacement. Then find with a regex if starts or ends with space(one or more times), returns the field.

```
   awk -F'|' 'function trim(field){
   gsub(/^ +| +$/,"", field); 
   return field
   }{
   OFS=",";
   print trim($2),trim($3)}' stations > lista.csv
```

With this code is enougth

And the file *stations* is with this structure:

```
     1 | UTAR | U de Tarapacá                   
     3 | VALN | Valparaíso                      
     4 | JRGN | Junta Gorgino                   
     6 | TRPD | Torpederas
```