# awk equivalent of LTRIM function in C

Tags: arrays, linux, string, bash, awk

I need to delete leading 0s only from a string. I found that there is no in-built function like LTRIM as in C.

I'm thinking of the below AWK script to do that:

```
awk -F"," 'BEGIN { a[$1] }
   for (v in a) {
       {if ($v == 0) {delete a[$v]; print a;} else exit;}
   }'
```

But guess I'm not declaring the array correctly, and it throws error. Sorry new to AWK programming. Can you please help me to put it together.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I trim white space from a variable in awk?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9985528/how-can-i-trim-white-space-from-a-variable-in-awk)

Comment: There isn't a function `LTRIM()` in standard C (nor `ltrim()`).  If you're used to using said function, it is a non-standard extension for the environment you work in.

Comment: You're asking us to help you do something that may not need to be done at all. See http://xyproblem.info/. Post sample input and expected output so we can see what you want to do, as opposed to how you think you need to do it, so we can start to help you.

Comment: @EdMorton Probably used the word "thinking" in the wrong context. I did already try the above and it threw an error. Will be more cautious to put proper "inputs" and "outputs" while posting queries in future. Thanks a lot for the pointer

Comment: No, the word `thinking` was fine, it's just that there's a LOT of different ways to trim leading zeros and they all make sense in different contexts so unless you tell us WHY you want to trim leading zeros we're just throwing out a bunch of code, any/all of which could be completely wrong for your application even though they all do trim leading zeros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `awk`, as requested:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
/^0$/   { print; next; }
/^0*[^0-9]/ { print; next; }
/^0/    { sub("^0+", "", $0); print; next; }
        { print $0; }
```

This provides for not trimming a plain "0" to an *empty string*, as well as avoiding the (probably) unwanted trimming of *non-numeric* fields.  If the latter is actually desired behavior, the second pattern/action can be commented out.  In either case, substitution is the way to go, since adding a number to a non-numeric field will generate an error.

Input:

```
0
0x
0000x
00012
```

Output:

```
0
0x
0000x
12
```

Output trimming non-numeric fields:

```
0
x
x
12
```

Comment: That could be written much more concisely as `awk '/^0[0-9]+$/{sub(/^0+/,"")}1' file`.

Comment: I was allowing for the possibility of input like `0123,456`

Comment: Ah, I see. As good a guess as any at the problem the OP is trying to solve! Adding a number to a non-numeric field won't generate an error, btw, the non-numeric field will just be treated as a string with numeric value zero.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a somewhat generic `ltrim` function that can be called as `ltrim(s)` or `ltrim(s,c)`, where c is the character to be trimmed (assuming it is not a special regex character) and where c defaults to " ":

```
function ltrim(s,c) {if (c==""){c=" "} sub("^" c "*","",s); return s}
```

This can be called with 0, e.g. `ltrim($0,0)`

NOTE:

This will work for some special characters (e.g. "*"), but if you want to trim special characters, it would probably be simplest to call the appropriate sub() function directly.

Comment: You can't use that when `c` is a some regexp metachars, e.g. `.`. You need `sub("^[" c "]+",...`.

Comment: ... unless c is "^" ... but I've revised to clarify. Thanks for your vigilance.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure it'd work for "\" either but it gets you closer. Maybe `"^\" c "+"`? idk...

Answer (score 2):

Based on other recent questions you posted, you appear to be struggling with the basics of the `awk` language.

I will not attempt to answer your original question, but instead try to get you on the way in your investigation of the [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) language.

It is true that the syntax of awk expressions is *similar* to [c](/questions/tagged/c). However there are some important differences.

I would recommend that you spend some time reading a primer on awk and find some exercises.  Try for instance the Gnu Awk [Getting Started](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Getting-Started.html#Getting-Started).

That said, there are two major differences with `C` that I will highlight here:

1. Types

Awk only uses strings and numbers -- it decides based on context whether it needs to treat input as text or as a number.  In some cases
you may need to force conversion to string or to a number.

2. Structure

An Awk program always follows the same structure of a series of *patterns*, each followed by an *action*, enclosed in curly braces: *pattern* `{` *action* `}`:

```
pattern { action }
pattern { action }
.
.
.
pattern { action }
```

Patterns can be regular expressions or comparisons of strings or numbers.
If a pattern evaluates as *true*, the associated action is executed.

An empty pattern always triggers an *action*. The `{` action `}` part is optional and is equivalent to `{ print }`.

An empty pattern with no action will do nothing.

Some patterns like `BEGIN` and `END` get special treatment. Before reading  stdin or opening any files, *awk* will first collect *all* `BEGIN` statements in the program and execute their associated actions *in order*.

It will then start processing stdin or any files given and subject each line to all other pattern/action pairs *in order*.

Once all input is exhausted, all files are closed, and *awk* will process the actions belonging to all `END` patterns, again in order of appearance.

You can use `BEGIN` action to initialize variables. `END` actions are typically used to report summaries.

A warning: Quite often we see people trying to pass data from the shell by   partially unquoting the *awk* script, or by using double quotes.  Don't do this; instead, use the *awk* `-v` option to pass on parameters into the program:

```
a="two"
b="strings"
awk -v a=$a \
    -v b=$b \
'BEGIN {
    print a, b
}'
two strings
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. You got my problem right. Lately doing a lot of file content manipulations ( and pretty big files) at my work. Came to know awk is the fastest in these scenarios. Thanks again for getting me started...with AWK.

Comment: Just trying to address your *need* - which was the underlying theme of your questions.

Answer (score 1):

you can force `awk` to convert the field to a number and leading zeros by default will be eliminated.

e.g.

```
$ echo 0001 | awk '{print $1+0}'

1
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, and you just want to trim the leading `'0'`s from a value in bash, you can use `sed` to provide precise regex control, or a simple loop works well -- and eliminates spawning a subshell with the external utility call. For example:

```
var=00104
```

Using `sed`:

```
$ echo "$var" | sed 's/^0*//'
104
```

or using a *herestring* to eliminate the *pipe* and *additional subshell* (bash only)

```
$ sed 's/^0*//' <<<$var
104
```

Using a simple loop with *string indexes*:

```
while [ "${var:0:1}" = '0' ]; do
    var="${var:1}"
done
```

`var` will contain `104` following 2 iterations of the loop.

Comment: This doesn't handle the special case where the value is zero.

Comment: It was never intended to handle the *trivial* case. An additional test of the result would be all that is required.