# How to add SHA hash column dynamically to (every row in) CSV file?

Tags: bash, csv, hash

I have multiple CSV files with the next format:

```
"name","last_name","birth_day","register_date"
Michael,Jackson,August 29 - 1958,August 29 - 1958
Claude,Shannon,April 30 - 1916,April 30 - 1916
```

I want to transform each file to the next format:

```
"name","last_name","birth_day","register_date",sha256
Michael,Jackson,August 29 - 1958,August 29 - 1958,9949a1af67a3fb465eca01ca884f5ec7cd280078a39a0430a0f352bf19e16685  -
Claude,Shannon,April 30 - 1916,April 30 - 1916,fb464b3ab4f3f3db2384e192135cde97486ce96fe34e391a3294e5076f800aae  -
```

That means I want to add the "sha256" column with the hash values.

So far I could get the hash values for each row but I don't know how to add this value as a column "sha256" to the CSV file.

```
for file in ${DIR}/csv/*
do
    while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
        echo -n $line | shasum -a 256
            /**
              Here it calculates the hash per row, and I want to add it
              at the end of the row as "sha256" column
            **/
    done < "$file"
done
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`awk`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html) to do this, it will work for `GNU awk` >= 4.1.0 :

```
awk -i inplace '
function rtrim(s) { sub(/[ \t\r\n]+$/, "", s); return s }
{
    if (FNR > 1){
        cmd = "echo -n \""$0"\" | shasum -a 256"
        while (cmd | getline line) {
            split(line, arr, "-")
            print $0","rtrim(arr[1])
        }
        close(cmd)
    }
    else {
        print $0",sha256"
    }
}' ${DIR}/csv/*
```

- `-i inplace` is used to edit the files in place
- `FNR` is the current record number in the current file
- see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20648953/2614364) for passing variable to a shell command
- the `sha256` command result is splitted according to `-` delimiter in order to only keep the sha256 value. [`rtrim`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27158086/2614364) is used to remove the extra space

Comment: It looks wonderful; however, it throws: `/usr/local/bin/awk: Argument list too long`. It is because of the line breaks?

Comment: Whats the output of `awk --version` ?

Comment: awk version 20070501, on macos. There are thousands of CSV files inside that folder.

Comment: you can use `gawk` , install it with `brew install gawk`

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't you just echo the hash value after the line?

```
for file in ${DIR}/csv/*
do
    while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
        hash=$(echo -n $line | shasum -a 256 | cut -d\  -f1)
        echo $line,$hash
    done < "$file"
done
```

The `cut` strips the trailing `-` from the `shasum` output. Add quotes around `$hash` if you like.

You should consider skipping the header line for each csv.