# awk: if column empty not working

Tags: awk

Everyone on the internet says you should use this:

```
if ($2 == "")
```

or this:

```
if (!length($2))
```

or this:

```
if (!$2)
```

All of these do not work for me. I got a `csv`, separated by ";" with 2 columns. In some cases the second column is empty (I can see that in gedit).

I want to distinguish the `2 sets` in that file (`2 sets = last column empty vs last column not empty`). If I just `print length($2)`, I see that those lines where there is nothing in column 2 actually have a length of 1.

So there seems to be something in there, but I cannot see what it is?

How can I make that thing visible, which makes length equal to 1? It seems to be preventing those 3 expressions from above from matching.

Comment: Please show some sample data and a bigger piece of the code that fails on your system. One thing that comes to my mind is that you have Windows line endings `\r\n`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Everyone on the internet...

Seriously? :)

My guess is that the second column contains a `\n` or a `\r`, which is invisible, but counts as having a length of 1. Have a look at this:

[How can I trim white space from a variable in awk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9985528/how-can-i-trim-white-space-from-a-variable-in-awk)

Comment: yes seriously, in every thread they teach those :P thank you, it was indeed windows newlines which caused the trouble (\r\n -> just kicked out the \r with sed). with linux newlines all those 3 expressions mentioned above work!

Comment: I've never said it. I guess I'm not on the internet.

Comment: Well, at least [the girls](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Rule%2037) won't say that.