# Convert an output in table format to a comma separated table in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I have an output similar to this

```
No Type  Pid    Status  Cause Start Rstr  Err Sem Time Program          Cl  User         Action                    Table
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 0 DIA    10897 Wait          yes   no     0   0    0                                    NO_ACTION                           
 1 DIA    10903 Wait          yes   no     0   0    0                                    NO_ACTION                           
 2 DIA    10909 Wait          yes   no     0   0    0                                    NO_ACTION                           
 3 DIA    10916 Wait          yes   no     0   0    0                                    NO_ACTION                           
 4 DIA    10917 Wait          yes   no     0   0    0                                    NO_ACTION                           
 5 DIA     9061 Wait          yes   no     1   0    0                                    NO_ACTION
```

But I want this table to be comma separated and fields with no values should print null instead of taking the output of next column!
Currently I am receiving the below output.

```
NO=0,Type=DIA,Pid=10897,Status=Wait,Cause=yes,Start=no,Rstr=0,Err=0,Sem=0,Time=NO_ACTION,Program=,Cl=,User=,Action=,Table=
NO=1,Type=DIA,Pid=10903,Status=Wait,Cause=yes,Start=no,Rstr=0,Err=0,Sem=0,Time=NO_ACTION,Program=,Cl=,User=,Action=,Table=
NO=2,Type=DIA,Pid=10909,Status=Wait,Cause=yes,Start=no,Rstr=0,Err=0,Sem=0,Time=NO_ACTION,Program=,Cl=,User=,Action=,Table=
NO=3,Type=DIA,Pid=10916,Status=Wait,Cause=yes,Start=no,Rstr=0,Err=0,Sem=0,Time=NO_ACTION,Program=,Cl=,User=,Action=,Table=
NO=4,Type=DIA,Pid=10917,Status=Wait,Cause=yes,Start=no,Rstr=0,Err=0,Sem=0,Time=NO_ACTION,Program=,Cl=,User=,Action=,Table=
NO=5,Type=DIA,Pid=9061,Status=Wait,Cause=yes,Start=no,Rstr=1,Err=0,Sem=0,Time=NO_ACTION,Program=,Cl=,User=,Action=,Table=
```

I have written a script to do the same but It's not including the columns with null values.

```
#!/bin/bash
sed 1,5d test.txt > temp.txt
input="temp.txt"
while IFS= read -r line
do
echo $line | awk 'BEGIN{FS=" ";OFS=","}{print "NO="$1,"Type="$2,"Pid="$3,"Status="$4,"Cause="$5,"Start="$6,"Rstr="$7,"Err="$8,"Sem="$9,"Time="$10,"Program="$11,"Cl="$12,"User="$13,"Action="$14,"Table="$15;}'
#echo "$line"
done < "$input"
```

Comment: Is your file tab separated?

Comment: It's a mix of tab and space!

Comment: @Nitish: What would be a "null value" in your example?

Comment: There are some fields with no values, so I want to replace them with "Null" keyword. for ex. - If you see the original output, then there are fields like 'cause', 'program' etc. which have no values.

Comment: But then we can't see a "field", except if we define that each field occupies a certain number of characters.

Comment: @Nitish: Hence you know the exact number of characters in each field?

Comment: @user1934428 Probably, No!

Comment: It seems like SQL output, if you have access to a database, you can correct output using something like `... , IFNULL(Cause, 'NULL'), ...`

Comment: @Nitish: Then you have to explain: If you get a line `0 0  3   5`, are these 4 fields, or are these 5 fields with one being null?

Comment: 5 fields with one being null!

Answer (score 1):

I am not experienced with `awk` which can obviously make the task much faster and shorter.
Although this can be done with a `bash` script as follows:

```
if [ "$#" -ne "2" ]
then
    echo "usage: <$0> input_file output_file"
    exit 1
fi

#input table file
input_file=$1
output_file=$2


#Get name for a temporary file by mktemp
temp_file=`mktemp headings_XXXXXX` 

#Store all headings separated by '\n' in a temporary file
sed -n '1p' $input_file | tr -s ' ' '\n' > $temp_file


headings=$(sed -n '1p' $input_file)

counter=0


#This loop would extract width of each column so that they can be given to cut as parameters
# like `cat filename | cut -b 3-8` would extract the entries in that column
while [ 1 ]
do
    upper_limit=${#headings}
    headings=${headings% [! ]*}
    lower_limit=${#headings}

    if [ "$upper_limit" = "$lower_limit" ]
    then
        limits_for_cut[$counter]=$(echo "1-${upper_limit}")
        counter=$( expr $counter + 1 )
        break
    fi

    lower_limit=$( expr $lower_limit + 1 )

    limits_for_cut[$counter]=$(echo "${lower_limit}-${upper_limit}")

    counter=$( expr $counter + 1 )

done


end_index=$( expr $counter - 1 )

no_of_lines=$( cat $input_file | wc -l )
no_of_lines=$( expr $no_of_lines - 2 ) #first 2 lines in file are for headings and dashes

on_line=$no_of_lines

#This loop will output all data to the specified file as comma separated
while [ $on_line -ne 0 ]
do
    counter=$end_index

    cat $temp_file |
        while read heading
        do
            tmp=$( expr $no_of_lines - $on_line + 1 + 2 )
            echo  "${heading}=`sed -n "${tmp}p" $input_file | cut -b ${limits_for_cut[$counter]} | sed 's/ //g'`," >> $output_file
            if [ $counter -eq 0 ]
            then
                break
            fi
            counter=$( expr $counter - 1 )
        done

    on_line=$( expr $on_line - 1 )
done    

echo `cat $output_file | tr -d '\n'` > $output_file

rm $temp_file
```

Basically, we are doing this with `cut` command.

Like for header “type" which lies between `3-8`, we can simply do like this
`cut -b 3-8 filename`.

I ran this on `OSX`. You may need to change `cut` and `sed syntax` to suit your machine.

If this solution suits you, you should try the same with `awk` because that would make it much faster and shorter.

Answer (score 1):

Based on `awk` you can easily achieve this, by counting length of fields (computed with the 2 firsts lines) and then retrieving `substr`ings from the current line.
Here is a proposal that does what you want, and that parses the header from the input (this works for one file at a time)

```
# FIELD array to store start/len for each field
# --- Functions from https://stackoverflow.com/a/27158086/5868851
function ltrim(s) { sub(/^[ \t\r\n]+/, "", s); return s }
function rtrim(s) { sub(/[ \t\r\n]+$/, "", s); return s }
function trim(s) { return rtrim(ltrim(s)); }
# --- Header parsing BEGIN
NR == 1 {
    for (i = 1; i < NF; ++i) {
        field_len = index($0,$(i+1)) - 1 - total
        FIELD[i, "start"] = total
        FIELD[i, "len"] = field_len
        FIELD[i, "name"] = $i
        total += field_len
    }
    last_field = $NF
}
NR == 2 {
    # Last field is of len length($0) - total
    FIELD[i, "start"] = total
    FIELD[i, "len"] = length($0) - total
    FIELD[i, "name"] = last_field
    FIELD_N = i
}
# --- Header parsing END
# --- Data parsing BEGIN
NR > 2 {
    sep=","
    for(i = 1; i <= FIELD_N; ++i) {
        value = trim(substr($0, FIELD[i, "start"], FIELD[i, "len"]))
        if (!value)
            value="null"
        if (i == FIELD_N)
            sep="\n"
        printf("%s=%s%s", FIELD[i, "name"], value, sep);
    }
}
# --- Data parsing END
```