# Find and replace text inside xml document using regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

I am using c# console app to get xml document. Now once xmldocument is loaded i want to search for specific href tag:

```
href="/abc/def
```

inside the xml document.

once that node is found i want to strip  tag completly and just show Hello.

```
<a href="/abc/def">Hello</a>
```

I think i can simply get the tag using regex. But can anyone please tell me how can i remove the href tag completly using regex?

Comment: using regex for this kind of stuff is a bad idea IMHO - if you are dealing with HTML then I would recommend using HTML Agility pack...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using C# Regular expression to replace XML element content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448376/using-c-sharp-regular-expression-to-replace-xml-element-content)

Comment: @KenWhite - that is totally different question i looked at it. But no help for my question.

Comment: @Yahia - It is not html i am loading the xml file in xml document and want to find that particular link and remove <a href tag from that. That is why i think regex is a better way to go with. What you think?

Comment: @NoviceMe, if you can show your xml, I guess you can get better answers

Comment: @NoviceMe there is no link in XML, what you have shown is HTML...

Answer (score 1):

xml & html same difference: tagged content. xml is stricter in it's formatting. 
for this use case I would use transformations and xpath queries rebuild the document. As @Yahia stated, regex on tagged documents is typically a bad idea. the regex for parsing is far to complex to be affective as a generic solution.

Answer (score 0):

The most popular technology for similar tasks is called XPath.  (It is also a key component of XQuery and XSLT.)  Would the following perhaps solve your task, too?

```
root.SelectSingleNode("//a[@href='/abc/def']").InnerText = "Hello";
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
string x = @"<?xml version='1.0'?> 
 <EXAMPLE>  
    <a href='/abc/def'>Hello</a> 
 </EXAMPLE>";

 System.Xml.XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
 doc.LoadXml(x);
 XmlNode n = doc.SelectSingleNode("//a[@href='/abc/def']");
 XmlNode p = n.ParentNode;
 p.RemoveChild(n);
 System.Xml.XmlNode newNode = doc.CreateNode("element", "a", "");
 newNode.InnerXml = "Hello";
 p.AppendChild(newNode);
```

Not really sure if this is what you are trying to do but it should be enough to get you headed in right direction.